# How can I specify custom choices for the django_filters DateRangeFilter function?

Tags: django, django-filters

I am using the django_filters DateRangeFilter() function.  My filter class looks like this:

```
class ListingFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    ship_docking = django_filters.DateRangeFilter()
    class Meta:
        model = Listing
        fields = ['orig', 'dest', 'ship_sailing', 'ship_docking']
```

I want to change the choices of range - default choices are Today, Yesterday, Past 7 days, etc.  How can I specify a different list of choices?

Thanks and regards...Paul (Django newbie)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking out the source code for `django-filter` and the `DateRangeFilter`, we can see that on `__init__` it checks if a choices set and a filters set has been passed in, if they are empty, it uses the defaults.

```
class DateRangeFilter(ChoiceFilter):
    choices = [
            ('today', _('Today')),
            ('yesterday', _('Yesterday')),
            ('week', _('Past 7 days')),
            ('month', _('This month')),
            ('year', _('This year')),
        ]
    
        filters = {
            'today': lambda qs, name: qs.filter(**{
                '%s__year' % name: now().year,
                '%s__month' % name: now().month,
                '%s__day' % name: now().day
            }),
            'yesterday': lambda qs, name: qs.filter(**{
                '%s__year' % name: (now() - timedelta(days=1)).year,
                '%s__month' % name: (now() - timedelta(days=1)).month,
                '%s__day' % name: (now() - timedelta(days=1)).day,
            }),
            'week': lambda qs, name: qs.filter(**{
                '%s__gte' % name: _truncate(now() - timedelta(days=7)),
                '%s__lt' % name: _truncate(now() + timedelta(days=1)),
            }),
            'month': lambda qs, name: qs.filter(**{
                '%s__year' % name: now().year,
                '%s__month' % name: now().month
            }),
            'year': lambda qs, name: qs.filter(**{
                '%s__year' % name: now().year,
            }),
        }
    
        def __init__(self, choices=None, filters=None, *args, **kwargs):
            if choices is not None:
                self.choices = choices
            if filters is not None:
                self.filters = filters
```

All you have to do is create a list of sets for your choices and then copy the format for your custom filters and then:

```
class ListingFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    // Put custom choices and filter variables here
    choices = [...]
    filters = { ... }
    ship_docking = django_filters.DateRangeFilter(choices=choices, filters=filters)
    class Meta:
        model = Listing
        fields = ['orig', 'dest', 'ship_sailing', 'ship_docking']
```

Comment: Thanks Harben, That works great.  I had to copy the _truncate function from the django_filters source, but otherwise no problems:

def _truncate(dt):
    return dt.date()